# Can't concatenate string with Move-Item (A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument)

Tags: powershell

Trying to concatenate a basic string in Powershell with a **wildcard** for moving everything that has a specific extension with the function **Move-Item**:

```
Move-Item $location + "\*" + $extension -destination $destination
```

**When using this line I get an exception:**

```
Move-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '+'.
At C:\Users\username\Documents\Scripts\NWI\move-files.ps1:17 char:21
+ ...             Move-Item $location + "\*" + $extension -destination $des ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Move-Item], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36309828/258523) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36309806/258523) cover the solution but don't explain the problem. The problem is a parsing issue.

Powershell sees a command `Move-Item`, one named flag/argument `-destination $destination` and five unnamed arguments `$location`, `+`, `"\*"`, `+` and `$extension`.

You need to force it to parse the command the way you want it to by putting `()` around the string concatenation.

Alternatively move it to its own assignment.

```
$src = $location + "\*" + $extension
Move-Item $src -Destination $destination
```

Comment: Great answer Etan. I accepted your answer as it gives me an understanding of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
Move-Item -Path $($location + "\*" + $extension) -Destination $destination
```

Should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
 Move-Item ($location + "\*" + $extension) -destination $destination
```